# Twilio + Stripe connector + Pay<> verb - how to pass additional information?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, stripe-payments, twilio

I have setup a Stripe connector in my Twilio system, and am calling the [Pay functionality](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pay/pay-connectors) in my controller. I note that the only field I can modify to send information to Stripe is the "description" field of the Stripe payment entry. I actually need to do 2 other things:

1. Update the "customer" field with the phone number of the caller.
   [image]
2. Send through a GUID, which correlates to a table and entry in our database, so that the Stripe webhook we are listening for (`payment_intent.succeeded`/`payment.charged` etc) will contain that GUID, which gives our code further flexibility. E.g. it would be good to update the metadata property below? Anything that would achieve our aims.

[image]

We have spent a significant amount of time researching the above two questions and can't find, which seems very odd as this seems like a very basic question. Sorry to bother, does anyone have any information?

Failing this, I guess we would have to use the description itself, and perhaps ammend it once done?

Here's my code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult TakeStripePayment(PaymentId id, VoiceRequest request)
    {

        var response = new VoiceResponse();

        var payment = (from p in _DbContext.Payment where p.Id == id select p).Single();

        var subMeter = (from p in _DbContext.SMPSupplyMeter where p.Id == payment.SMPSupplyMeterId select p.SubMeter).Single();
        var meterNo = ShortMeterNo(subMeter.Serial.ToString());
        response.Say("You will now be asked to enter your card details. After entering digits, press the hash key to move on to the next question.");
        var pay = new Pay(paymentConnector: _config.PaymentConnector.ToString(), 
            description: PaymentUtility.GetDescriptionForPaymentGateway(payment) + $" {request.From}", 
            timeout: 15, currency: "gbp", chargeAmount: $"{Math.Round(payment.Amount.Value)}", postalCode: "false", 
            action: new Uri($"/voice/AfterPay?id={payment.Id}", 
            UriKind.Relative));
       // something here to send the number and GUID? e.g. pay.SetOption() or pay.Parameter()? Example?
        var prompt = new Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Prompt(for_: Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Prompt.ForEnum.PaymentCardNumber).Say("Please enter long card number.");
        pay.Append(prompt);
        prompt = new Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Prompt(for_: Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Prompt.ForEnum.ExpirationDate).Say("Please enter the expiration date as 4 digits.");
        pay.Append(prompt);
        prompt = new Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Prompt(for_: Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Prompt.ForEnum.SecurityCode).Say("Please enter the three security digits on the back of the card.");
        pay.Append(prompt);
        prompt = new Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Prompt(for_: Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Prompt.ForEnum.PaymentProcessing);
        pay.Append(prompt);
        response.Append(pay);
        return TwiML(response);
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "Twilio + Stripe connector + Pay". But answering your two questions with the Stripe API:

1. When you create a PaymentIntent, you can set a [`customer`](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-customer) property. And that Customer object has a [`phone`](https://docs.stripe.com/api/customers/create#create_customer-phone) property you could set.
2. If you need to store arbitrary information on the PaymentIntent object (like an internal ID), you should use the [`metadata`](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-metadata) property. You can learn more about how `metadata` works [here](https://docs.stripe.com/api/metadata?gclid=CNWp5sPv28wCFYKAkQod-SUPMw).

Comment: Thanks but this would be for general stripe api, but the Pay is the twilio method I am using which doesn't allow for setting these things (or if it does, it's not clear how and I need to know how). See: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pay/pay-connectors. I've updated the question with further information

Comment: @RabbiKaii I'm not familiar with this Pay Twilio connector. You could try asking Twilio support directly.

Comment: I have, and will forward their answer if they have one

Answer (score 0):

From Twilio support:

> You can pass custom parameters via the parameter noun like:

```
<Pay paymentConnector="stripe"> 
   <Parameter name="metadata_testKey" value="value" /> 
</Pay>
```

> Anything that is prefixed with metadata_  will land in the Stripe metadata for the transaction. You can also pass it via the Parameter  field in the start pay session request if they're using agent assisted pay. This works for charges and reusable tokens, but Stripe does not support metadata for one time tokens.

The way I did this in my C# code:

```
   var pay = new Pay(paymentConnector: _config.PaymentConnector.ToString(), 
        description: PaymentUtility.GetDescriptionForPaymentGateway(payment) + $" {request.From}", 
        timeout: 15, currency: "gbp", chargeAmount: $"{Math.Round(payment.Amount.Value)}", postalCode: "false", 
        action: new Uri($"/voice/AfterPay?id={payment.Id}", 
        UriKind.Relative));
    pay.Parameter("metadata_number", request.From);
    pay.Parameter("metadata_GUID", payment.Id.ToString());
```

If there is any way to update the customer information, I will update this answer.